# Table create error when adding a 'ON DELETE SET NULL'

Tags: mysql

I am getting a `General 1005, Can't create table` error when I try to set foreign key restraints using `ON DELETE SET NULL`.

I can set the foreign keys with ON DELETE RESTRICT or CASCADE with no problems

```
ALTER TABLE `users` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT users_domain_id_foreign 
    FOREIGN KEY (`domain_id`) 
    REFERENCES `domains` (`id`) 
    ON DELETE RESTRICT 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

However I need it to set null on delete but this just isn't working. Setting the foreign key with `ON DELETE SET NULL` throws a 1005 can't create table error as described above. Can anyone shed some light on why this won't work?

```
ALTER TABLE `users` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT users_domain_id_foreign 
    FOREIGN KEY (`domain_id`) 
    REFERENCES `domains` (`id`) 
    ON DELETE SET NULL 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

(mySQL 5.5.24, all tables are InnoDB)

Additional : Just in case anyone asks, `domain_id` is an unsigned integer and is an index. The referenced `id` is an auto incremented id.

Comment: is domain_id nullable?

Comment: No it wasn't... and it now works! Thanks for that spot!

Comment: @palindrom Yes please do add as an answer